# node.js/JavaScript syntax - add extra parameter to passed parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax

I'm building a REST API using node.js/Express.

I have some middleware applied to certain routes. I have a JavaScript syntax error which I can't resolve.

`server.js`

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()


const watchdogController = {
  ping: function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('watchdog')
    res.status(200).send('woof!')
    //next()
  }
}
const middleware = function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('middleware')
  next()
}
const middleware2 = function(req, res, next, roles) {
  console.log('middleware2')
  //console.log(roles)   //I want to be able to view the roles here!
  next()
}


//This line is where I have the issue...
router.get('/watchdog', middleware, middleware2, watchdogController.ping)



module.exports = router
```

I need to be able to pass an array of roles to `middleware2`. E.g.

`router.get('/watchdog', middleware, middleware2(...['ordinary','supervisor']), watchdogController.ping)`

But this syntax fails :(

`node server.js` results in:

```
middleware2
undefined
/Users/asdf7/Desktop/asdf7/lib/router.js:19
  next()
  ^

TypeError: next is not a function
    at middleware2 (/Users/asdf7/Desktop/eoh/lib/router.js:19:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/asdf7/Desktop/eoh/lib/router.js:26:37)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/asdf7/Desktop/asdf7/index.js:2:16)
```

This works:

`router.get('/watchdog', middleware, middleware2, watchdogController.ping)`

But now I can't see any roles in middleware2 ;( I need to be able to view the roles array in the `middleware2` function.

I can't figure out what syntax to use... Can you guys help?

Comment: As long as whatever is in the params to `get` is a middleware, you can *create* that middleware however you want. The easiest would be to create a function that returns your middleware--and you'd pass your roles into the middleware creator function.

Comment: A middleware in express has next format (req, res, next). If you need to pass info, you must attach this info to the request in a previous middlewares, example on middleware1 you can add req.roles = 'WHATEVER'; and after the next call, you would be able to access to req.roles on middleware2.

Comment: @DaveNewton Really appreciate your reply. I'm not sure how this would work. Create middleware? The best I can come up with sofar is replace `middleware2` with: `(req,res,next) => { middleware2(req,res,next,['ordinary','supervisor']) }`. I thought I could use the spread operator, but not sure how to...

Comment: @JoseMato I have several dozen routes (not just '/watchdog'). I'm trying to pass the roles alongside the route to keep the syntax clean. middleware1 is an isolated function for auth. I don't want it to stuff parameters (and figure out what parameters to stuff). I just want to inject the roles array on the same line as where the route is defined. My goal here is clean syntax rather than "making it work".

Comment: No. `createMiddleware2 = roles => { return function (req, res, next) { doSomethingWithRolesEtc... } }`

Comment: @DaveNewton Wow! Standing ovation! JavaScript syntax is amazing... Thanks so much. I updated the answer.

Comment: @Mr Ed, agree making the things clear but if you use a framework you play with framework rules and in express is a bad practice modify the middlewares in the way you are doing it, also, middlewares with 4 parameters are the way that express indicate is a middleware to handle errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution (with thanks to @DaveNewton):

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()


const watchdogController = {
  ping: function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('watchdog')
    res.status(200).send('woof!')
    //next()
  }
}
const middleware = function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('middleware')
  next()
}
const middleware2 = roles => function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('middleware2')
  console.log(roles)
  next()
}

router.get('/watchdog', middleware, middleware2(['ordinary','supervisor']), watchdogController.ping)



module.exports = router
```

Comment: Glad it worked out. Note that there may be other and/or better solutions to this, especially as I haven't used Express for a long time now--poke around in their middleware docs and look at some examples to see if there's a cleaner way.